# How to use GraphQL mutation in Next.js without useMutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, graphql-mutation

I'm working on a codebase with `Next.js` version 9.3.0 and `GraphQL`. To get the benefits of Next.js optimizations, we are wrapping each page in `withApollo`, so inside the pages we can make use of `useQuery`, `useMutation`.
The issue I'm facing is that I need to use mutation in the `Header component` which is outside the page, which doesn't have access to `ApolloClient` because the app is not wrapped in `withApollo`.

The error I'm getting is this `Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.`

The `Header` component is inside the `Layout` component like this:

```
<>
   <Meta />
   <Header/>
   {children} // pages which are composed with withApollo
   <Footer />
</>
```

Instead of using `useQuery` in a component **without** `withApollo` is easy you can use

```
import { createApolloFetch } from 'apollo-fetch';

const fetch = createApolloFetch({
    uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_SERVER,
});

const userInfoQuery = `{
    userInfo {
        loggedIn
        basketCount
        wishListCount
    }
}`;

const userInfoData = fetch({
      query: userInfoQuery,
});
```

Is there an alternative solution for `useMutation` in a component not composed with `withApollo`?

Any suggestions are welcomed,
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, mutations work with Apollo fetch too

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-fetch#simple-graphql-mutation-with-variables but this is not maintained anymore

The solution that worked for me, in the end, was to still `useMutation` and to pass the client to it. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#usemutation-api

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import createApolloClient from 'lib/apolloClient';
import loginUser from 'mutations/login';

const [getToken, { data: mutationData, error: loginErrors, loading }] = useMutation(loginUser, { client: createApolloClient()});
```